# Getting specific values from Solve to plug into function

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have four functions of four variables, `f1,f2,f3,f4` and `x,y,z,theta`. I solve these using

```
ff = Solve[{f1 == 1, f2 == 1, f3 == 1, f4 == 1}, {x, y, z, \[Theta]}]
```

and it gives me eight answers

```
{{x -> -1.70956, y -> 0.139101, z -> -1.79726, \[Theta] -> -2.68743},
 ..., 
{x -> 1.70956, y -> -0.139101, z -> 1.79726, \[Theta] -> 0.45}}
```

How do I now get each of these and plug into a function `f5` defined as

```
f5 = x^2 + y^2 + log(z) + Sin[\[Theta]]
```

for instance?

Comment: `f5 /. ff` (This is covered in ref guide page for `Solve` e.g. under Scope > Basic Uses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
f5/.ff
```

`ReplaceAll` (abbreviated `/.`) is your friend when dealing with such things.